# HMaster process doesn't run on hadoop multi-node cluster after HBase installation

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I install a hadoop multi-node cluster on top of tow ubuntu virtual machines.

In next step I trying to installing HBase on this virtual cluster. But when I running HBase with `start-hbase.sh`, `HMaster` not running on master although `HRegionServer` has been run correctly on master and slave machines.

`hbase-env.sh` file contents:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HBASE_OPTS="$HBASE_OPTS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false
```

`hbase-site.xml` file contents:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
            <value>hdfs://machine-a:54310/hbase</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
            <value>/usr/local/zookeeper</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
            <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
            <value>2181</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
            <value>machine-a</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

`zoo.cfg` file contents:

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/usr/local/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
```

Running zookeeper:

```
ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default 
Using config: /usr/local/zookeeper 3.4.13/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
Starting zookeeper ... /usr/local/zookeeper 3.4.13/bin/zkServer.sh: line 140: ./zookeeper.out: Permission denied
STARTED
```

Running HBase:

```
/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.2/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2358: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_USER: bad substitution
/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.2/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2453: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_OPTS: bad substitution
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hbase-2.1.2/lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
running master, logging to /usr/local/hbase-2.1.2/logs/hbase-saeed-master-machine-a.out
/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.2/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2358: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_USER: bad substitution
/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.2/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2453: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_OPTS: bad substitution
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop-3.1.2/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hbase-2.1.2/lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
saeed@machine-b: running regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase-2.1.2/bin/../logs/hbase-saeed-regionserver-machine-b.out
saeed@machine-a: running regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase-2.1.2/bin/../logs/hbase-saeed-regionserver-machine-a.out
```

Comment: Same problem here but not sure about the root cause.
I rollback hbase version to 2.0.4. to make it work first.

Comment: I think you need to delete the a redundant file in the CLASSPATH first. with 
sudo rm /usr/local/hbase-2.1.2/lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar 
then see what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar logs showing up when trying to start hbase.
When I looked in the master logs could see the following:

> 2020-05-25 16:18:20,529 ERROR [master/VB-hbase:16000:becomeActiveMaster] master.HMaster: ***** ABORTING master vb-hbase,16000,1590403688901: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown. *****
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The procedure WAL relies on the ability to hsync for proper operation during component failures, but the underlying filesystem does not support doing so. Please check the config value of **'hbase.procedure.store.wal.use.hsyn**c' to set the desired level of robustness and ensure the config value of 'hbase.wal.dir' points to a FileSystem mount that can provide it.

I then followed the [steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50389483/326733)

Apparently there might not be a direct link to the error we see for invalid variable logged during the start and master not coming up, as I could still see the error but all seems to work fine till now.

Answer (score 0):

this maybe help(hbase 2.3.7)

add this line to /etc/profile( or ~/.bashrc)
then source /etc/profile

```
export HBASE_DISABLE_HADOOP_CLASSPATH_LOOKUP=true
```

in $HBASE_HOME/bin/hbase, there are some code like this

```
#If avail, add Hadoop to the CLASSPATH and to the JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH
# Allow this functionality to be disabled
if [ "$HBASE_DISABLE_HADOOP_CLASSPATH_LOOKUP" != "true" ] ; then
    HADOOP_IN_PATH=$(PATH="${HADOOP_HOME:-${HADOOP_PREFIX}}/bin:$PATH"  which hadoop 2>/dev/null)
fi
```