# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/htrace/core/HTraceConfiguration

Tags: java, hbase

I am using hadoop 2.9.1 and hbase 2.1.0 at stand-alone local mode.

When I tried staring HBase 2.1.0 using `sudo start-hbase.sh` at bin folder, I got below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/htrace/core/HTraceConfiguration
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2983)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.core.HTraceConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
```

This is my `hbase-site.xml`

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
        <value>/home/niyazmohamed/bigdata/upgraded_versions/hbase-2.1.0/hbasedir</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
        <value>localhost</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
        <value>2181</value>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
        <value>/home/niyazmohamed/bigdata/upgraded_versions/hbase-2.1.0/zookeeper</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

When I tried to start HBase version 1.2.0 , it started successfully and `hbase shell` was also accessible and CRUD operations were successful.

Hadoop and HBase path are set. Only by that , I was able to run HBase-1.2.0.

Only with HBase-2.1.0, this problem occurs.

Any help appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If existing answer doesn't work let me know and I can take a look.

Comment: Existing answer didn't work as expected,after copying the jar, HMaster is starting, but I get java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused error at zookeeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related:
[Starting HBASE, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.SamplerBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106952/starting-hbase-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-htrace-samplerbuild)

`htrace-core-*-incubating.jar` was missing from some early versions of HBase 2.x

If the `htrace-core` `jar` is in `$HBASE_HOME/lib/client-facing-thirdparty`

copy the `jar` to `$HBASE_HOME/lib`, otherwise

Download the Jar from Maven [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/htrace/htrace-core4/4.2.0-incubating/htrace-core4-4.2.0-incubating.jar)

and place into `$HBASE_HOME/lib`

You can see in HBase `pom.xml` for version `hbase 2.1` that `htrace 4.2.0` is the correct version of the dependency.
https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/rel/2.1.0/pom.xml#L1364

Goodluck.

Comment: Existing answer didn't work as expected,after copying the jar, HMaster is starting, but I get java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused error from zookeeper when I checked at logs. Is there any specific things I am missing?

Comment: Did a quick search and found https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase/2.1.0 The version of org.apache.htrace is different 4.2.0-incubating . Try using https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.htrace/htrace-core4/4.2.0-incubating instead. @MohamedNiyaz

Comment: Verified that org.apache.htrace.core.HTraceConfiguration exists in this jar as well (you can just use a zip browser of any kind to do that)

Comment: Now this error had gone, HMaster is starting but got error like ```zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x1753c71c8d40001 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused ```

Comment: what version of zookeeper are you using? Not sure if this is the correct package but usually version numbers align. I see for hadoop-common 2.9.1 it lists zookeeper version 3.4.6 as a dependency. Did you upgrade your hadoop version or just HBase? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common/2.9.1
 @MohamedNiyaz use @ my username so I get notified

Comment: Actually in the hbase link I sent earlier it lists 3.4.10 as the zookeeper version. So it sounds like it needs to be in 3.4.x series but better to try one of these 2 versions that I mentioned above.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari , I am using hadoop-2.9.1 , just upgraded HBase from 1.2.0 to 2.1.0 and got this issues. My zookeeper version is 3.4.10 but stillat ```hbase-env.sh```, I had mentioned  export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true ,so not sure , if zookeeper is a problem

Comment: I had set this property at ```hbase-site.xml``` and all errors are gone and HMaster started up. Refered to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709569/hbase-error-illegalstateexception-when-starting-master-hsync for solving issue. Thanks to @OmarAbdelBari for helping out.

Comment: The question was originally about class not found so you should mark an answer.

Comment: I had upvoted the comment suggesting to use different version of htrace (4.2.0) @OmarAbdelBari

Comment: Indeed, `htrace` packaged with HBase `2.1` is  `htrace 4.2.0` https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/rel/2.1.0/pom.xml#L1364
I'll update the answer with the correct link for other users.

Answer (score 0):

the version of hbase i used is 2.4.15,in my case ,the htrace-core jar is in `$HBASE_HOME/lib/client-facing-thirdparty`,named `htrace-core4-4.2.0-incubating.jar`

copy the jar to $HBASE_HOME/lib, then the problem solved